# Git Recover Local Commit

Tags: git, github

I've been working on a project.

I ended up having several errors start happening on me. Thinking that I did something stupid, I wanted to check a previous commit.

So I first did this:

```
git add .
git commit -am 'half baked code'
```

I did not push it up (since I wasn't sure if I broke anything).

I then did:

```
git checkout xdfsfsfs
```

grabbing a previous commit where I know everything worked.

I'm not trying to get back to my unpushed local commit.

```
git reset --hard
```

seems to bring me back to the latest commit on github, but not to the local commit.

`git log` doesn't show my commit

Is there anyway for me to recover the local commit? Or do I just need to re-code it? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for `git reflog`

This shows all actions undertaken in git even if not saved.

To fix this you're going to want to do

`git reflog`

Find the sha of the commit you made previously

`git checkout SHA`

`git checkout -b mycommit`

now you can merge this into your master or wherever it needs to go.

Answer (score 2):

`git reflog` to the rescue! This command will show you the commits where `HEAD` has been pointing lately.

You can check them, one by one, and when you find the one you want, just `git reset --hard <HASH>` to that. The comment to the right of the wanted `<HASH>` will be something like `checkout: moving from <previous branch> to xdfsfsfs`

You can also use the `HEAD@{3}` notation, but I advise not to use it, as the meaning of `HEAD@{3}` changes each time you change `HEAD`.

As as footnote, you can also use `git reflog <branch>` and it will show you where that branch has been pointing to. Without the branch name it will show the `reflog` of `HEAD`.

Comment: I have been save from a dramatic situation thanks to your answer. Couldn't recover my branch before using checkout on HEAD@{xxx}

Answer (score 0):

When you did

```
git checkout xdfsfsfs
```

that changed `HEAD`; but it didn't change any branches.  So all you have to do is go back to the branch you were on before you did that.  For example, if you were committing changes to `master` then you would just say

```
git checkout master
```

The other answers suggesting reflog would apply if you had "lost" the commit, such as by resetting the branch away from it.  When they tell you to find the commit and `reset` back to it, that will cause a problem for you, because when you did the initial checkout you went to detached head state - which is fine on its own, but if you reset to the commit you will remain in detached head, which will cause headaches when you want to commit more code.

You did checkout to get off the branch, so you want to do checkout to get back on the branch.

Answer (score 0):

If you have deleted your commit (drop commit) by mistake, Android Studio Event log has a message

> 5:47 PM   Commit Dropped
> Undo

Use this undo to undo your delete