# how to recovered remote branch commits that have not been push

Tags: git, github, inversion-of-control

I got some error in code editor so i have to delete the folder and reset all over again. and I have commit almost all the major changes that made in my branch but I have not push to the branch. now I am in the same branch. but I am not able to see any of unpush commit in this branch. I have done lots of changes to it should have almost  four -five commits to this branch. now I am trying to recover my un publish commits from the same   branch.

Please shared me your knowledges, how i can get all my commits that have not push to branch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git Recover Local Commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48545662/git-recover-local-commit)

Answer (score 0):

If you've simply deleted the files in the repository folder that were previously committed, you can run the following command. Keep in mind this will also reset all un-committed changes.

```sh
git reset --hard HEAD
```

But, if you deleted the entire repository folder, you're unfortunately out of luck. Git creates a hidden `.git` folder within the root project folder, which contains all information about the repository and its commits. This folder (and the commits inside) will have been deleted along with the project folder.